# Namespace in Code-Behind causing BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.page_aspx' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, namespaces

I am trying to get a web application processing through TFS and MS Release Management. The project builds fine and when run in debug mode from within Visual Studio - however when it comes to publishing it through TFS & Release Management I get the error:

> BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.ivmain_aspx'

I have been looking all over the place to find out what might be causing this but with not too much luck. This is a pretty big web application developed over the years by various developers and have found that some pages have a namespace declared within the Code-Behind... Those that do not were operating correctly so I removed the Namespace from my one problem page and it then loaded fine!

So, there is obviously something with the Namespace that is confusing the publication. I could just go through and find all codebehind files with Namespaces and take them out - but the three following reasons are putting me off doing so:

- There may be genuine reasons these Namespaces were added
- There are loads of these pages with Namespaces and it would be a mammoth task to go through them all.
- Im still not really sure 'why' this is causing the problem - there may be a better/more appropriate fix to the actual problem.

Has anyone else experienced this same problem and have any advice?

EDIT

---

The top of the aspx page looks as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Masters/DefaultMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ivmain.aspx.vb" Inherits="iAssess.ivmain" %>
```

and the namespace is declared in the codebehind as follows:

```
Namespace iAssess

    Partial Public Class ivmain
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

If I however remove the namespace in the Inherits value and then remove it from the codebehind I get no problems.

Comment: What version of .NET are these being built to?

Comment: The IIS (v7) Application pool is set to v4.0 as is the target framework in the apps web.config file.

Comment: Are you missing references in the project to anything? Check if there are any broken references (the yellow exclamation mark) but you may also have some of the necessary Microsoft assemblies missing as well.

Comment: Thanks pay - I don't think so though as the project works fine in debug and if hosting the project files in IIS. I am only getting this problem after it is published/Built through TFS/Release Management.

Comment: I could still be off the mark on my response there though!

Comment: You may share your publish steps here. And check this case to see whether it is helpful: http://forums.asp.net/t/955888.aspx?BC30456+InitializeCulture+is+not+a+member+of+

Comment: Thanks Cece - I have added my answer below. I had also come across that page a few times when searching. The reason that couldn't help me is because I am using TFS and Release Management to publish and Release my files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the inherits namespace from all files that referenced it and then removed the namespace from each respective Code Behind file. It all seems to be working fine now.